# I need to change a Select option to use a mysql table query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following select input for a form.  The form works fine and eventually the selection gets inserted into a ysql table.  What I want now is to replace the select with a dropdown that uses a query of a mysql table.  Here is what I have now.  The mysql table has the same fields in it as the select provides.

```
  <td><form action="">
  <select name="lk1">
    <option value="0">Not used</option>
    <option value="1">Conference</option>
    <option value="2">Forward</option>
    <option value="3">Transfer</option>
    <option value="4">Hold</option>
    <option value="5">DND</option>
    <option value="6">SMS</option>
    <option value="7">Directed Pickup</option>
    <option value="8">Call Park</option>
    <option value="9">DTMF</option>
    <option value="10">Voice Mail</option>
    <option value="11">Speed Dial</option>
    <option value="12">Intercom</option>
    <option value="13">Line</option>
    <option value="14">BLF</option>
    <option value="15">Prefix</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lk1value"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lk1label"></td>
    </tr>
```

I also, later in my project want to edit the info in a form that I want to allow the same dropdown or similar to let the user change the setting.  That code is:

```
echo "<tr><form action='update.php' method='post'>"; 
  echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'></td>";   
  echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='name' 
  value='".$row['templatename']."'>
  </td>";
  echo"<td><input type='text' name='keyname1' value='".$row['keyname1']."'>
  </td>";
  echo"<td><input type='text' name='lk1label' value='".$row['lk1label']."'>
  </td>";
  echo"<td><input type='text' name='keytype' value='".$row['keytype']."'>
  </td>";
  echoecho"<td><input type='text' name='lk1' value='".$row['lk1']."'></td>";
  "<td><input type='text' name='lk1value' value='".$row['lk1value']."'>
  </td>";
  echo "<td><input type='submit'>";
  echo"</form></tr>";
```

It would replace the keytype value.

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.  Right now I am just trying to get this to work.  Cleaning it up will come later as I get this working as proof it can do what I need.

Thanks again

Comment: You didn't say where/what is the problem. Select from the database? Create the dropdown? update the values? what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the select options from your table in the database you can do the following

```
<select name="lk1"> 

<option value="0">Not used</option>

    <?php

    // write your query here

    While( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)  ){

    //Get the fields you want to put in options

    //Example

       $id = $row['id'];
       $title = $row['title'];
    }
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id ?>">
    <?php echo $title ?>
    </option>

    <?php } ?>


    </select>
```

This will loop the options and all your value will be placed for user to select

Comment: Thanks, editing it to fit my situation and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had done this in another place and added it to my page.  Very similar to what was offered.  My problem now is that the first column in the first row shows data, the second column shows the dropdown (populated) and the rest of the columns and rows are blank.  Where did I go wrong?

```
 ?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
    echo "<tr><form action='update.php' method='post'>"; 
    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'></td>";   
    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='name' value='".$row['templatename']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='keyname1' value='".$row['keyname1']."'><readonly</td>";
    echo"<td></select><select name='keyname'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['keytype'] . '">' . $row['keyname'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo"</select></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='lk1value' value='".$row['lk1value']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='lk1label' value='".$row['lk1label']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit'>";
    echo"</form></tr>";
    echo "<tr><form action='update.php' method='post'>"; 
    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'></td>";   
    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='name' value='".$row['templatename']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='keyname2' value='".$row['keyname2']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='lk2label' value='".$row['lk2label']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='lk2' value='".$row['lk2']."'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='lk2value' value='".$row['lk2value']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit'>";
    echo"</form></tr>";
```

Where have I gone astray?